# Weird citation of stack exchange question

Tags: feature-request, citation

I want to cite a question and its answer in my paper in IEEEtran format. However, citing the question gives me this weird result:

[image: Weird Citation]

The URL of my account is broken and the author name is just the beginning of my username.

I would be happier if it had the form:

C. Koca (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/426569/c-koca), “Summation of
$\sum_{n=0} a^nq^{n^2} $ ,” Mathematics Stack Exchange, `uRL: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738807` (version: 2020-07-06). [Online]. Available: `https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738807`.

Alternatively "C-koca" or "c-koca" would be useful as well.

How can I cite it in this way? I tried to change the bibtex text generated by stackexchange, yet I couldn't manage it properly. Also, a feature handling the username and hyphen in the link as itself would be handy.

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks to the suggestion of u/Martin Sleziak, I managed to fix the broken URL. However, the name issue persists. In IEEE citation, `Name Surname` is cited as

`N. Surname`

However, when usernames are involved, there is no surname, so it is treated as a single name lacking a surname. I checked the [IEEE reference guide](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf) but couldn't spot something relevant.

This issue might be about bibtex itself so it might be impossible to solve it.

Comment: Does using hyperref package and enclosing the urls into `\url{...}` help? I mean something like: `AUTHOR = {C.Koca (\url{https://math.stackexchange.com/users/426569/c-koca})}`. And similarly for the link to the question. (Maybe also changing "C.Koca" to "C. Koca" might be a reasonable thing to do; i.e., adding the space.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak `\url{}` helped with the broken URL. Thanks! For the name, I used it as `{C. Koca}` with a space but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is not reddit, by the way.

Comment: u/Asaf Karagila beat me to it! :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know, but I never noticed if there is convention to refer to someone here. Not giving `u/` reduces the information in my opinion. It might easily refer to someone who is not on stack exchange, especially if the user removes the comment. If there is a convention to refer to other users here, please let me know.

Comment: You could also check [tex.se] to see whether there are some suggestions how to cite a Stack Exchange post. I was able to find this one: [What should an BibTeX entry for a Stack Exchange post look like?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267998).